# CXF Webservice server calling Axis1 webservice as client Problem (Unable to locate a valid EngineConfigurationFactory)

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, axis, cxf

I have a CXF webservice server calling a Axis1 webservice as cliente and getting the follow error:

"Unable to locate a valid EngineConfigurationFactory" and then, null pointer exception

I'm using Jboss4.

Is there any problem using axis1 and cxf at the same application?

Follow stack trace

10:25:04,263 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:25:04,263 WARN  [EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder] Factory org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet Ignored: missing required method: public static EngineConfigurationFactory newFactory(Object).
10:25:04,264 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:25:04,264 WARN  [EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder] Factory org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryDefault Ignored: missing required method: public static EngineConfigurationFactory newFactory(Object).
10:25:04,264 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:25:04,264 ERROR [EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder] Unable to locate a valid EngineConfigurationFactory
10:25:04,270 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:25:04,270 INFO  [serviceauthenticatorImpl] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Service.(Service.java:113)
    at ServiceAuthenticator_pkg.ServiceAuthenticatorServiceLocator.(ServiceAuthenticatorServiceLocator.java:12)
    at br.com.druid.zanfa.serviceauthenticator.impl.serviceauthenticatorImpl.executa(serviceauthenticatorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:255)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:461)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:188)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The explosion has naught to do with CXF. Axis has exploded in its client library. You should be able to isolate this to a test case that has no CXF  in it.

However, it may not be easy to get help with Axis1 to resolve the problem. Plan on reading the source.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have divided my project using EJB and everything has work automatically. I think there is a problem working together with CXF and AXIS1. I will study more and update here with the result.